# Bootstrap class not loading in barryvdh PDF in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, dompdf, laravel-snappy

I have used barryvdh PDF to generate PDF of my Invoice template.

To create Invoice template i have created one blade in laravel and applied bootsrap css in it.

while loading that blade it look proper with bootstrap classes loaded. But when i generate the PDF it takes my style.css but Bootstrap class does not load.

Here is my lump_sum_invoice_template_1.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title page-title></title>
    <link href='https://app.dayjibe.com/app/styles/fonts.googleapis.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://app.dayjibe.com/app/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="bodyopacity" landing-scrollspy id="page-top">
<!-- Main view  -->
<div>
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title">

                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <div class="form-group" >
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <img src="###LOGOPATH###" style="width:100px;height:50px;margin-top:2em;" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top:1em;">
                            <div class="col-sm-4" style="float:right; " >
                                <div class="form-group" style="clear:both;line-height:0;" >
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="width:115px;text-align:right;">
                                        <strong>Invoice Date:</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 input-group" style="text-align:left;">
                                        ###INVOICEDATE###
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group" style="clear:both;">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="width:115px;text-align:right;">
                                        <strong>Project#:</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0;text-align:left;">
                                        ###PROJECTNUMBER###
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group" style="clear:both;padding-top:0.5em;" >
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="width:115px;text-align:right;">
                                        <strong>Invoice#:</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0;text-align:left;">
                                        ###INVOICENUMBER###
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group" style="clear:both;padding-top:0.5em;" >
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="width:115px;text-align:right;">
                                        <strong>Due Date:</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 input-group" style="text-align:left;">###DUEDATE###
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top:1em;">
                            <div class="col-lg-8" >
                                <div class="form-group" >
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <label class="control-label">###CLIENT###</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top:1em;">
                            <div class="col-lg-8" >
                                <div class="form-group" >
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <label class="control-label">###CLIENTADDRESS###</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top:1em">
                            <div class="col-sm-8 input-group" >
                                <div class="col-sm-8 input-group date" style="float:left;text-decoration:underline;margin-left:2em;">
                                    <strong>Professinal Service from&nbsp;###INVOICEFROMDATE###&nbsp;&nbsp;to&nbsp;&nbsp;###INVOICETODATE###</strong>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top:2em;">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:90%;margin-left:2em;" >
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="col-sm-1" rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:center;">Contract Type</th>
                                    <th class="col-sm-2" rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:center;" >Phase Name</th>
                                    <th class="col-sm-1" rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;">Contract Amount</th>
                                    <th class="col-sm-2" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;" >Previously Invoice</th>
                                    <th class="col-sm-2" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">Current Period</th>
                                    <th class="col-sm-2" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">Current Balance</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center;">% OR Unit</th>
                                    <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center;">Amount</th>
                                    <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center;">% OR Unit</th>
                                    <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center;">Amount</th>
                                    <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center;">% Unit</th>
                                    <th class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:center;" >Amount</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="9" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:center;"><strong>###INVOICEDATA###</strong></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-show="projectInvoice.PhaseData.total_phase_data.length > 0">
                                    <td class="col-sm-1" colspan="2" ><strong>Totals for Phases</strong></td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:right;">$###CONTRACT-TOTAL-AMOUNT###</div></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1" ></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:right;">$###CONTRACT-TOTAL-PREVIOUS-AMOUNT###</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1" ></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:right;">$###CONTRACT-TOTAL-CURRENT-PERIOAD-AMOUNT###</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1" ></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align:right;">$###CONTRACT-TOTAL-CURRENT-BALANCE-AMOUNT###</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="8"><strong>TOTAL AMOUNT DUE THIS INVOICE</strong></td>
                            <td>###INVOICETOTALDUE###</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top:2em;">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my laravel code

```
return PDF::loadView('InvoiceTemplates/lump_sum_invoice_template_1')->save(public_path().'/lump_sum_invoice_template_1.pdf')->stream('download.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Dompdf up to and including 0.7.0 does not sufficiently support the CSS used by Bootstrap.

The upcoming 0.7.1 release should address many of these deficiencies.

Updates on support are posted to the Dompdf issue tracker, [#631](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/631).